# Game Engine: Class parameter

Tags: c++, game-engine

I am doing university work for a game engine and we needed to do an agnostic code. They told us to do the rest on our own and I am on the right track however, when I try and pass the parameters for the function it says it doesn't pass for the arguments? This I believe is due to the class parameter that I have on there. Am I being an idiot or ?

Error: (without Buffer Layout) function arguments don't match. Or with the code you can see it says "Expected an expression"

Please help!

Vertex Buffer

```
/* \file OpenGLVertexBuffer.cpp */
#include "engine_pch.h"
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include "include/independent/platform/OpenGL/OpenGLVertexBuffer.h"


namespace Engine
{
    void BufferLayout::addElement(BufferElement element)
    {
        m_elements.push_back(element);
        calcStrideAndOffset();
    }

    void BufferLayout::calcStrideAndOffset()
    {
       uint32_t l_offset = 0;

        for (auto& element : m_elements)
        {
            element.m_offset = l_offset;
            l_offset += element.m_size;
        }

        m_stride = l_offset;
    }


    OpenGLVertexBuffer::OpenGLVertexBuffer(void * vertices, uint32_t size, BufferLayout layout) : m_layout(layout)
    {
        glCreateBuffers(1, &m_OpenGL_ID);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_OpenGL_ID);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    }

    OpenGLVertexBuffer::~OpenGLVertexBuffer()
    {
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_OpenGL_ID);

    }

    void OpenGLVertexBuffer::edit(void * vertices, uint32_t size, uint32_t offset)
    {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_OpenGL_ID);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, size, vertices);
    }

}
```

Rendering API

```
/* \file renderAPI.cpp */

#include "engine_pch.h"

#include "rendering/RenderAPI.h"
#include "rendering/indexBuffer.h"
#include "rendering/vertexBuffer.h"

#include "platform/OpenGL/OpenGLIndexBuffer.h"
#include "platform/OpenGL/OpenGLVertexBuffer.h"

#include "systems/log.h"

namespace Engine
{
    RenderAPI::API Engine::RenderAPI::s_API = RenderAPI::API::OpenGL;

    IndexBuffer * IndexBuffer::create(uint32_t * indices, uint32_t count)
    {
        switch (RenderAPI::getAPI())
        {
        case RenderAPI::API::None:
            Log::error("No supported Rendering API");

        case RenderAPI::API::OpenGL:
            return new OpenGLIndexBuffer(indices, count);

        case RenderAPI::API::Direct3D:
            Log::error("Direct3D not currently Supported!");

        case RenderAPI::API::Vulkan:
            Log::error("Vulkan not currently Supported!");


        }
    
    }

    VertexBuffer * VertexBuffer::edit(void* vertices, uint32_t size, uint32_t offset)
    {
        switch (RenderAPI::getAPI())
        {
        case RenderAPI::API::None:
            Log::error("No Supported Rendering API");

        case RenderAPI::API::OpenGL:
            //return new OpenGLVertexBuffer(vertices, sizeof(size), offset);
            new OpenGLVertexBuffer(vertices, size, <BufferLayout> offset);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to "new OpenGLVertexBuffer" expects three arguments

- a void*
- an uint32_t
- a `BufferLayout`

You pass

- vertices, a void* (okay)
- sizeof(size) - wrong. It calculates the size of the variable(!) `size`, which is 4 (uint32 is always 32 bits/4 bytes). So you pass the constant 4 as the second parameter. Not what you want.
- offset - wrong again. The third parameter is expected to be of type `BufferLayout`. You are trying to pass a `uint32_t`, where you should be passing a `BufferLayout`.

In general you need to read up on types (why is uint32_t not a `BufferLayout`), functions (parameters), constructors.

Also you are missing `break` statements in your switch. Study the `switch` statement to see what I mean.

And you are using pointers (return `new something`). If they teach you that in university then the course you are taking is very outdated. As a beginner you should NEVER have to use pointers, NEVER work with `new`. You could use the C++ standard ways of `std::shared_ptr<VertexBuffer>` instead, using `std::make_shared...` rather than `new`. The problem with pointers is that they are just too easily mishandled. You will forget to call `delete` in the proper place(s), which will lead to memory leaks. Or you will call `delete` in the wrong places, which will lead to 'use after free' or 'calling delete for a deleted pointer'. `shared_ptr` and similar classes take off the burden and will do the work for you.

The need for pointers has been *greatly* diminished in modern C++.

Finally: When you post a question, please include
a: the *exact* compiler error
b: the *exact* location, where this error occurs.

You could for example include a `// ERROR MESSAGE HERE` comment in your example code.
Both points will make it much more likely that someone answers your questions.

Comment: Thank You ! I do have a base understanding but I need to pracitse with them more to really get my head round it more.